# How do I list a folder and return all the file names of a specific file type?

Tags: path, rust

I have written a CSV parser that allows the user to enter a query string and a CSV file as positional arguments and parses the specified file for the query.

I'd to automatically search the current directory for CSV files and search them for the string, but I am having problems processing these items and returning them for use in other functions.

My current code for the folder search:

```
fn folder_search() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

    //let mut v = Vec::new();

    for path in paths {
        let path = path.unwrap().path();

        match path.extension() {
            Some(p) if p == "csv" => println!("{:?}", path.file_name().unwrap()),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

For now, I'm just printing out the file extension. I'd like to return these files for further use, but I am not sure how .

I guess I could assign these files to a vector and return the vector, but I'm not sure how to assign them to the vector.

If I `push` the `path` inside  `match path.extension() {...}` I get an error than `path` does not live long enough, which I understand, but I don't know how the correct way of fixing this is.

Comment: Are you aware of https://crates.io/crates/csv?

Comment: Yeah I am using it in parsing the CSV-files, but I have not found a way to pass all csv-files in a folder to the `Reader`-struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path` borrows the actual path representation. You must use `PathBuf` that is the owned equivalent:

```
use std::{ fs, io, path::PathBuf, ffi::OsStr };

fn list_of_csv_paths(root: &str) -> io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    let mut result = vec![];

    for path in fs::read_dir(root)? {
        let path = path?.path();
        if let Some("csv") = path.extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) {
            result.push(path.to_owned());
        }
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", list_of_csv_paths("./"));
}
```

---

I advice you to use [`glob`](https://crates.io/crates/glob) that does the job much more easily.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. I had to adapt my CSV parsing function a bit but now it works. Thanks also for the edit on my OP, `Some(p) if p == "csv"` looks much cleaner.

Comment: @rongon https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards